# Svelte reactivity affected by initial variable value

Tags: svelte

I've started working with Svelte and I stumbled upon some unexpected behavior. This is the snippet of my app source

```js
let currentPage = 1;
$: if (currentPage || $selectedOption) {
    fetchPage(currentPage, $selectedOption);
}

async function fetchPage(page: number, option: string) {
    //...
}

onMount(() => {
    fetchPage(currentPage, $selectedOption);
});
```

When I load the page for the first time `fetchPage()` function is called twice. However, if I'll make this change `let currentPage = 0;` it is properly called only once. The problem is that I need to have `currentPage` value initially set to 1.

I've tried also this change:

```js
let currentChange = 0;
// ... rest the same
onMount(() => {
    fetchPage(currentPage, $selectedOption);
    currentPage = 1;
});
```

But this didn't help as well. Similarly any bool flags set in `onMount()` and then checked in if statement didn't help.

Any suggestion what else can I do?

Comment: Wouldn't going with your first solution WITHOUT `onMount(...)` work?

Comment: Ok, I am speechless... You are 100% correct. I don't understand why my approach didn't work (with `onMount()`) but your suggestions works like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: If you have both `onMount()` and `$: if(currentPage || $selectedOption){`, then both will try to fetch the page when the user comes to the page IF `currentPage` is truthy. `0` is the only number that is falsy, so for that number it's only `onMount()` that will fetch the page.

Comment: @PeppeL-G: Please add an answer, which then can be accepted.